# Adding Dll user control into wpf app.xaml file path shows error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll

I first create a usercontrol dll and inside that dll i coded for making styles for buttons. The code in dll is showned Below

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    </Style>
```

After that i added this reference to my main project as References-->Add References-->Browse-->mystyles.dll

Now i want to use this dll for making styles to buttons in my main project .So for that in app.xaml i added the code showned below

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/References;component/Resources/UserControl1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

But the error occurs ,I dont know the correct syntax for adding path ..Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had success with this format in the past.

```xaml
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/{dllname};component/{folderstructure}/{filename}.xaml" />
```

`dllname` is the name of the DLL without the extension

Comment: <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyStyles;component/References/UserControl1.xaml" />


still error Occurs while making changes.Please help me

Comment: Should this be `<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyStyles;component/Resources/UserControl1.xaml" />` based on your folder structure?  The folder structure I mention would be the folder structure of the project that generated the DLL and not the folder structure of the project using the DLL